# How do I use find to search files with a specific extension?

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression

We want to find the `.hprof` files under `/var`.

What is the difference between

```
find  /var -type f -regex '.*\.hprof'
/var/ff-efre-ferg-fr.hprof
```

and

```
find /var -type f -name "*.hprof"
/var/ff-efre-ferg-fr.hprof
```

Or the search approach are exactly the same?

Comment: The search pattern `.hprof` (as for extension) is too simple, the 2nd approach would be enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-name` predicate is standard, matches against the file name only and uses shell wildcard syntax.

The `-regex` is a non-standard extension, supported by a few `find` implementations but with different syntax and matches on the full path (starting with the path argument provided, here `/opt`).

The default syntax is some form or other of regular expressions. For example, with GNU `find`, that's GNU `emacs` regexp, and you can use different regex types with the `-regextype` predicate. With some BSDs, it's standard basic regular expressions and you can switch to standard extended regular expression with the `-E` option (not predicate).

There's another standard predicate: `-path` which like `-regex` matches on the full path and like `-name` uses shell wildcards.

Some implementations also support some `-iname`, `-ipath`, `-iregex` predicate to match case-insensitively. GNU `find` supports `-wholename` as an alternative to `-path` (rms objects to the word *path* referring to a full file name including some directory components).

```
find  /opt -type f -regex '.*\.hprof'
```

and

```
find  /opt -type f -path '*.hprof'
```

are equivalent with implementations that support `-regex`. Wildcard `*` and regex (all variants) `.*` both mean *any number of characters*.

They could give different results than

```
find  /opt -type f -name '*.hprof'
```

For files with path components other than the name that contain sequence of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale.

```
$ mkdir $'St\351phane'
$ touch $'St\351phane/file.hprof'
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ find . -regex '.*\.hprof'
$ find . -path '*.hprof'
$ find . -name '*.hprof'
./St?phane/file.hprof
```

That's a `Stéphane` directory but with the `é` encoded in iso8859-1 (0351, 0xe9), not UTF-8. In a UTF-8 locale, that 0xe9 byte doesn't map to a character, so regex `.` or wildcard `*` doesn't match on it (at least with GNU `find`). The file's base name (`file.hprof`) is OK though, so `-name` is able to match on it.

Some rules of thumb to maximise portability and reliability:

- use `-name` when you only need to match on the file names and not on in which directory it sits (and wildcard syntax is enough), like here for your `*.hprof` extension search.
- use `-path` if you also need to match on where the file is (like `find . -path ./special-dir -prune -o -type f -print`) (and wildcard syntax is enough).
- use `-regex` if wildcards are not enough, but check for support in the implementations you need to target, and beware, the regexp syntax may be different. If you need to match on the filename only, make sure you don't use operators that could match a `/`.